# document.getElementsByClassName("").innerHTML - not working

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have a div element with class name ***today*** in my html file and I am trying to print temperature on it, for that I have writen the following code but this is not printing anything on the div element, kindly help.

```
    $http.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22islamabad%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    .success(function (response) {
        var result = response.query; 
        var temp=result.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        var text=result.results.channel.item.condition.text;    
        var weather = $scope.weather = temp+" "+text;
        document.getElementsByClassName("today").innerHTML = weather;
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

`getElementsByClassName` has no definition for `innerHTML` because `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList object not an element. A `NodeList` is essentially a collection of elements.

If you need to return a single element then use `getElementById` and pass the id of the element. Or even better, since you're already using jQuery, you can do the following...

```
$('.today').html(weather);
```

Comment: Just to add, the fix is to access the first element in the nodeList: `document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0].innerHTML = weather;`

Comment: that'll do too...but I never trusted this method...

Comment: @Leo this would be against angular standards..controller should not play with the DOM https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: @PankajParkar absolutely right. But since the question itself is not directly related to AngularJS then I limited to the answer to the specific question. There could be a lot of things wrong in that code snippet (from an architectural perspective), for example making http requests from a controller is better moved to an injectable service

Answer (score 6):

The `document.getElementsByClassName("today")` would get a HTMLElement Collection. So it is better to change your code to:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0].innerHTML = weather;
```

Your final code should be:

```
$http.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22islamabad%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
.success(function (response) {
    var result = response.query; 
    var temp=result.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
    var text=result.results.channel.item.condition.text;    
    var weather = $scope.weather = temp+" "+text;
    $(".today").html(weather); // As you are using jQuery.
});
```

Or just:

```
$http.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22islamabad%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
.success(function (response) {
    var result = response.query; 
    var temp=result.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
    var text=result.results.channel.item.condition.text;    
    var weather = $scope.weather = temp+" "+text;
    document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0].innerHTML = weather;
});
```

But remember, that would update the first element. If your `.today` is second or third, this may not work and you might need tweaking of the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "ng-bind" directive in your view to your div. Example:

```
<div ng-bind="weather" class="today"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling document.getElementByClassName("today") it will return you collection of elements with specified class so you need to specify index of collection as follows :-

document.getElementsByClassName("today")[0].innerHTML = weather;

Answer (score 0):

You used angular js as seen in the javascript code, then use angular js functionality to assign value to element,

try this,

change html to

```
<div class='today'>{{myVariable}}</div>
```

and change javascript to

```
$http.get("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22islamabad%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys")
    .success(function (response) {
        var result = response.query; 
        var temp=result.results.channel.item.condition.temp;
        var text=result.results.channel.item.condition.text;    
        var weather = $scope.weather = temp+" "+text;
        $scope.myVariable = weather;
    });
```

(not tested, hope it works)

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted to bind html to element, you shouldn't do DOM manipulation from the angular controller. You could take use angular binding (Doing dom manipulation from controller is considered as bad practice).

You could use `ng-bind-html` directive on element which will add html as text to desired element. Addionally you need to make that html as trusted using `$sce` service `trustAsHtml` method.

**Code**

```
$scope.myVariable = $sce.trustAsHtml(weather);
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="today" ng-bind-html="weather"></div>
```

Or you could also make reusable filter which will make html as trusted html like below.

**Markup**

```
<div class="today" ng-bind-html="weather | trustedhtml"></div>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('trustedhtml', function($sce){
   return function(input){
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
   }
})
```